# Unable to establish connection to server on a static ip

Tags: google-app-engine, network-protocols, static-ip-address

Objective : I am trying to establish a test environment with a test server instance running on a static machine. I wish to be able to connect/make use/test code against this server running from all other machines on the same local network.

Problem : 
I am unable to establish a connection to the appserver that is running on a machine with static ip. It's an appengine server and runs without errors ( tested ). Connection can be established from the browser on the local machine but when trying to connect from any browser on another machine in the same network then no connection is established. 
The same setup is made available for jenkins server and jenkins dashboard can be accessed from all other machines in the network.

Comment: what IP have you set the dev_appserver (presumably) to listen on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running a local version of app engine, you can use the --host option.

```
dev_appserver.py --host=0.0.0.0 myapp
```

The host address to use for the server. You may need to set this to be able to access the development server from another computer on your network. An address of 0.0.0.0 allows both localhost access and hostname access. Default is localhost.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver

For java, use the --address option instead.